# How to only prepend selector only on first match?

Tags: jquery, media-queries, enquire.js

Using media-queries I've created a navbar which collapses, while my logo is at the bottom. With enquire.js I prepended the last li. How can I execute prepend only on the first match to prevent switching one li, each match to the right?

```
prependLogo : function() {

        query = "screen and (max-width: 979px)";
            handler = {
                match: function() {
                    $(.nav-collapse .nav).prepend($("li:last"));
                },

                unmatch : function() {

                },
            };

            enquire.register(query, handler);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to dealing with this problem. One is to utilise enquire's `unregister` method. The other is to utilise the `setup` callback and the `deferSetup` flag.

The `setup` callback is only ever called once. Usually it is called immediately when a query is registered, but combined with the `deferSetup` flag, setup is deferred until the query is first matched (unfortunately enquire expects there always to be a `match` callback, so we will just supply an empty function for this):

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 979px)", {
  setup : function() {
    $(.nav-collapse .nav).prepend($("li:last"));
  },
  deferSetup : true, 

  match : function() {}
});
```

The `unregister` method does as you might expect, unregistering a query. If we call `unregister` from within our match callback we can also achieve the same effect:

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 979px)", {
  match : function() {
    $(.nav-collapse .nav).prepend($("li:last"));
    //note this unregisters *all* handlers for this mq (if you have more than one) 
    enquire.unregister("screen and (max-width: 979px)"); 
  }
});
```

Here's a working example showing the two approaches: http://codepen.io/WickyNilliams/pen/vFLEH

Also, note in your code above, you're not using the `var` keyword to initialise your variables. This is bad practice in JS because any variable declared without `var` is attached to the global scope, which is probably not what you want :)